# Typescript typing error with forkJoin

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, rxjs5, fork-join

I'm experiencing a TypeScript type check failure when using the forkJoin operator form RxJS.
This is the code in question:

```
let products = this.http.get(productUrl, { headers: this.headers })
            .map(response => response.json().data as Product[]);
        let loans = Observable.of(loan);

        return Observable.forkJoin([products, loans])
            .map(data => {
                let resultProducts = data[0] as Product[];
                if (resultProducts.length > 0) {
                    lead.Product = resultProducts.find(i => i.ID == productId);
            }
            lead.Loan = data[1];
            return lead;
        });
```

The error tsc is emitting is:

```
 Type 'Loan' cannot be converted to type 'Product[]'.
```

My understanding of forkJoin is that data[0] should be a Product[] and data[1] should be a Loan, but tsc seems to disagree. Is my understanding incorrect? Am I missing some typing that would tell tsc hat I want?

Comment: lead.Loan = data[1]; return lead; is out of .map and Observable returns already, but I may be misguided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Observable.forkJoin without passing in an array.

```
// forkJoin with array
return Observable.forkJoin([products, loans])
// forkJoin without array
return Observable.forkJoin(products, loans)
  .map(data => {
    let resultProducts = data[0] as Product[];
    // ...
    lead.Loan = data[1];
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous [signature overloads for `forkJoin`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.3/src/observable/ForkJoinObservable.ts#L23-L39).

When you call `forkJoin`, passing an array:

```
Observable.forkJoin([products, loans])
```

The signature that's matched is this one:

```
static create<T>(
  sources: SubscribableOrPromise<T>[]
): Observable<T[]>;
```

Note that there is only a single type variable (`T`), so all of the array elements are inferred to be a single type. And `T` will be `Product[] | Loan`, which is why the error you mentioned is effected. (You cannot assert that something that could potentially be a `Loan` is a `Product[]`.)

If you specify separate arguments instead:

```
Observable.forkJoin(products, loans)
```

It will match this signature:

```
static create<T, T2>(
  v1: SubscribableOrPromise<T>,
  v2: SubscribableOrPromise<T2>
): Observable<[T, T2]>;
```

And the emitted value will have a tuple type `[Product[], Loan]` and the error won't be effected, as TypeScript will know that `data[0]` is a `Product[]`.

Comment: There is a limit though of 6 for the second signature type.