# Angular/RxJS: forkjoin with more than 6 parameters

Tags: angular, rxjs

I use forkjoin to initialize data before loading my page. Unfortunately I have reached the limit of 6 parameters for forkjoin:

```js
export class Sample implements OnInit {

  list1?: Pair[];
  list2?: Pair[];
  list3?: Pair[];
  list4?: Pair[];
  list5?: PairExt[];
  list6?: PairExt[];
  list7?: PairExt[];

  constructor(private http: HttpService,
              private httpWithCaching: HttpWithCachingService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initLists().subscribe(([list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6, list7]) => {
      this.list1 = list1;
      this.list2 = list2;
      this.list3 = list3;
      this.list4 = list4;
      this.list5 = list5;
      this.list6 = list6;
      this.list7 = list7;

      this.initModule();
    });
  }

  initLists(): Observable<[Pair[], Pair[], Pair[], Pair[], PairExt[], PairExt[], PairExt[]]> {
    return forkJoin([
      this.httpWithCaching.getList1(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList2(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList3(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList4(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList5(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList6(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList7()
    ]);
  }

  initModule(): void {
     //some requests and initialization after the lists were fetched...
  }
```

The code above will therefore no longer work as forkjoin is lmited to 6 parameters.

What would be the most simple solution for my case? All I want to do really is to fetch the lists before calling my `initModule`...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What RxJS version are you using? In 7.3 it should work the way you use it right now. https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-iguovh?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: Ahh good to know - I'm using 6.6

Comment: it works with 6.6.7 :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-iguovh?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: I would check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49542770/work-around-for-more-than-6-forkjoin-parameters

Answer (score -1, accepted):

NB: Not Tested

Try below to group the forkJoins

```typescript
   return forkJoin([
    forkJoin([
      this.httpWithCaching.getList1(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList2(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList3(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList4(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList5(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList6(),
    ]),
    forkJoin([
       this.httpWithCaching.getList7(),
       this.httpWithCaching.getList8(),
    ])

 ]).pipe(
     map( x => x.flat())
  );
```

The mapping is useful to transform the data back to 1 dimensional array

Comment: This looks good! Could you advise on an alternative for 'flat' perhaps? I use es2018 only.

Comment: Yes @TeaCup [].concat(...array)

Comment: didn't work for me unfortunately, but got it to work with arr.reduce((flat, toFlatten) => flat.concat(toFlatten), [])

Comment: Looks overcomplicated. It can be done easier.

Comment: You can spread the array in place of `flat`, something like `map( ([x1, x2]) => [...x1, ...x2])`

Answer (score 0):

Do it in other way:

```
  initLists(): Observable<[Pair[], Pair[], Pair[], Pair[], PairExt[], PairExt[], PairExt[]]> {
    return from([
      this.httpWithCaching.getList1(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList2(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList3(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList4(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList5(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList6(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList7()
    ]).pipe(combineLatestAll());
  }
```

That's it!

Comment: If you use old version of RxJS, then use `combineAll()` instead in pipe.

Comment: Why minus, strange?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps fallback to traditional approach, i.e. Promises. Use `Promise.all` to make the parallel API calls (similar to forkJoin). Given that in `forkJoin` would return an Observable nested over API calls that would `complete`, we can easily replace it with `Promise.all`

```
initLists(): Promise<[Pair[], Pair[], Pair[], Pair[], PairExt[], PairExt[], PairExt[]]> {
   const promises = [this.httpWithCaching.getList1(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList2(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList3(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList4(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList5(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList6(),
      this.httpWithCaching.getList7()];

   return Promise.all(promises);
}
```